# How to make a widget persistant in flutter even during navigation through different screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say I have a container on one side of the screen which I want to be present at all times even during navigation through different screens.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I can give you a solution but don't know if its the correct way to do that.

In the `MaterialApp` widget  there is a builder parameter which gives whole screen view as a parameter and can be wrapped up by another `Widget`. Here is an example.

```
MaterialApp(
  ....
  builder: (context, widget) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _myPersistantWidget(), // you can add your widget. May be inside Positioned widget?
        widget //this is the whole screen that we are wrapping in the stack
      ],
    );
  },
  ....
);
```